# Recursive Query in Oracle 21c to look back in the last 3 weeks

Tags: sql, oracle, recursion, oracle-sqldeveloper

Can you please help me in creating a recursive query in Oracle 21c or using other method to solve this problem.

My data has 3 columns: Ride, Client and Date.The column weeknum is added by me.

What I want is a recursive query or something similar to look back in the last 3 weeks taking in consideration each date and retrive the client/s who were present in at least 1 ride in the last 3 weeks(every week no exception) regarding each date, sum them and the result should be like in the column named Final Result.

I put DDL and DML statements in the db fiddle https://dbfiddle.uk/RT1G3uSp including my attemp but what I have tried is not working.
First I tried to put the conditions in the join then I tried to join on rn but is not the way it should be.

I want to clarify my request - for client number 1, I want to find out if he was present in any ride in the last 3 weeks and if he was present with at least one ride every week, then in week number 4 it should be marked with 1, in week number 5 and that's why the weeknumber column must also be taken into account,
client number 1 was present with a ride in weeks 2, 3 and 4 and again he must be marked with 1 and having a previous 1 we must now have 2.
in the week 6, client number 1 was present again with a ride in weeks 3, 4, 5 and again he must have 1 which, added to the previous 2, should have 3.

That's why I said recursive query, every time we have to go back to see if the respective client is present with at least one ride in each of the last 3 weeks. In this way should be applied for all the clients.

I hope it makes more sense now.

Please ask me if something is unclear again.

Thank you for your help in advance

```
Ride    Client  Date           Weeknum  Final Result
1         1    1/2/2023           1               0
2         1    1/5/2023           1               0
3         3    1/6/2023           1               0
4         1    1/11/2023          2               0
5         2    1/12/2023          2               0
6         1    1/16/2023          3               0
7         2    1/19/2023          3               0
8         1    1/24/2023          4               1
9         2    1/24/2023          4               0
10        1    1/30/2023          5               2
11        2     2/2/2023          5               1
12        2     2/8/2023          6               2
13        1     2/9/2023          6               3
```

Comment: Please post what your output should be based on your sample data

Comment: @Beefstu the column final result is the final output.
I will appreciate any hint or advice.
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could be solved by using `MATCH_RECOGNIZE`:

```
WITH cte AS (
   -- single instance per client,week
   SELECT  CLIENT, MIN(RIDE) AS RIDE, trunc(data,'IW') AS date_week_trunc
   FROM PROB
   GROUP BY CLIENT, trunc(data,'IW')
)
SELECT 
  MR.*
  ,COUNT(MR.CLS) OVER(PARTITION BY CLIENT ORDER BY date_week_trunc) AS final_result
FROM cte  T
MATCH_RECOGNIZE (
   PARTITION BY CLIENT
   ORDER BY date_week_trunc
   MEASURES CLASSIFIER() AS CLS
   ALL ROWS PER MATCH WITH UNMATCHED ROWS
   PATTERN (B+)
   DEFINE B AS (    B.date_week_trunc = PREV(B.date_week_trunc,1) + 7
                AND B.date_week_trunc = PREV(B.date_week_trunc,2) + 14
                AND B.date_week_trunc = PREV(B.date_week_trunc,3) + 21
               )
) MR
ORDER BY RIDE;
```

Output:

[image]

**[db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/_jDgYz9l)**

How it works:

- get single entry per client per start of the week - `date_week_trunc`
- check if there is entry for each of 3 previous weeks - `cls`
- compute running total - `final_result`

Comment: Lukasz Szozda Thank you so much for taking time in solving this problem.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use an outer apply to run a correlated subquery that matches the wanted conditions, and then use a combination of *case expression* and *running sum* to apply the additional logic added recently to the question.

```
select
    t.*
  , xtra.prior_rides
  , sum(case when xtra.prior_rides > 0 then 1 end) 
      over(partition by client order by weeknum ASC) as wanted_value
from prob t
outer apply (
  select 
       count(*) as prior_rides 
  from prob p
  where t.CLIENT = p.CLIENT
  and t.data > p.data
  and p.data <= t.data - 21
  ) xtra
order by client, data DESC
```

| RIDE | CLIENT | DATA | WEEKNUM | PRIOR_RIDES | WANTED_VALUE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 13 | 1 | 09-FEB-23 | 6 | 4 | 3 |
| 10 | 1 | 30-JAN-23 | 5 | 2 | 2 |
| 8 | 1 | 24-JAN-23 | 4 | 1 | 1 |
| 6 | 1 | 16-JAN-23 | 3 | 0 | *null* |
| 4 | 1 | 11-JAN-23 | 2 | 0 | *null* |
| 2 | 1 | 05-JAN-23 | 1 | 0 | *null* |
| 1 | 1 | 02-JAN-23 | 1 | 0 | *null* |
| 12 | 2 | 08-FEB-23 | 6 | 1 | 2 |
| 11 | 2 | 02-FEB-23 | 5 | 1 | 1 |
| 9 | 2 | 24-JAN-23 | 4 | 0 | *null* |
| 7 | 2 | 19-JAN-23 | 3 | 0 | *null* |
| 5 | 2 | 12-JAN-23 | 2 | 0 | *null* |
| 3 | 3 | 06-JAN-23 | 1 | 0 | *null* |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/rl6PHsP4)

**nb** This additional data included in the results above:

```
INSERT INTO PROB
 SELECT 12, 2, DATE '2023-02-08', 6 FROM DUAL union all
 select 13, 1, DATE '2023-02-09', 6 FROM DUAL;
```

It is possible that the running sum approach might need additional logic if there are "gaps" where no rides are found in the prior 21 days.

Answer (score 0):

My solution:

```
WITH cte_seq AS (
SELECT ride, client, data , weeknum, expected_output,
CASE WHEN
weeknum-lag(weeknum,3) OVER(PARTITION BY Client ORDER BY weeknum) = 3 THEN 1 END as flag
FROM (select a.*, row_number()over(partition by client, weeknum order by weeknum)as rn from prob1 a)a
where rn=1)
select ride, Client, data, weeknum, expected_output,
COUNT(flag) OVER(PARTITION BY Client, flag ORDER BY weeknum) as output
FROM cte_seq
ORDER BY client, weeknum;
```

Answer (score -1):

Something like this?

```
CREATE TABLE PROB ( RIDE, CLIENT, DATA) AS
SELECT 1,1, DATE'2023-01-02' FROM DUAL UNION ALL 
SELECT 2,1, DATE'2023-01-05' FROM DUAL UNION ALL 
SELECT 3,3, DATE'2023-01-06' FROM DUAL UNION ALL 
SELECT 4,1, DATE'2023-01-11' FROM DUAL UNION ALL 
SELECT 5,2, DATE'2023-01-12' FROM DUAL UNION ALL 
SELECT 6,1, DATE'2023-01-16' FROM DUAL UNION ALL 
SELECT 7,2, DATE'2023-01-19' FROM DUAL UNION ALL 
SELECT 8,1, DATE'2023-01-24' FROM DUAL UNION ALL 
SELECT 9,2, DATE'2023-01-24' FROM DUAL UNION ALL 
SELECT 10,1, DATE'2023-01-30' FROM DUAL UNION ALL 
SELECT 11,2, DATE'2023-02-02' FROM DUAL 

select client,trunc(data,'IW') wk, count(*)
    from   prob
    group by client, trunc(data,'IW')
    order by 2,1;
```

Comment: Beefstu
No the output should be the column final results.
so for client 1 he has present in a least 1 ride in the week  1,2,3 so in the week 4 he should have a 1 and then in week 5 another 1 because he is present in a ride in week 2,3 and 4.in week 5 for client 1 the output shoud be 2 because he already have a 1 in week 4.
I hope now make sense.So what you have try and i appreciate the attempt is not the correct output.